# How do I reduce private network latency below 0.5ms?

Tags: linux-networking, local-area-network, latency

We are migrating from one host to another. Our cluster consists of 10 dedicated linux servers which must communicate on a private network. At the old host we observed latencies below 0.2ms between our servers on their private interfaces, but on the new host they are around 0.5ms. I realize these are incredibly small numbers but we have built an application around the assumption of 0.2ms latency between our database and web servers and the new host's private network latency is effectively twice as high as the old network.

From my understanding our servers at the new host are in the same rack behind the same switch, much like they were at the old host. I believe the difference is they are on a VLAN at the new host while at the old host the servers were part of a large subnet consisting of all the host's customers. Could this VLAN be adding the 0.3ms of additional latency? What should I ask the datacenter techs to reconfigure?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are these dedicated servers or virtual? What is the speed of the physical NICs and switches?

Comment: They are dedicated. I was able to improve the latency by setting the latency-performance tuned profile.